# Accessing JSON data in Laravel controller from axios POST

Tags: php, laravel, axios

I am performing the following POST request from my React component:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/build',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        title: stateCopy.title,
        description: stateCopy.value,
        hunter: stateCopy.selectedHunter.id,
        encryption: stateCopy.encryption
    })
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response)
})
.catch(errors => {
    console.log("error: " + errors)
});
```

which posts to my Laravel controller where I would like to access `title`, `description`, `hunter` and `encryption`.

I tried a few options such as `request('title')`, `request()->post()` and `$request->getContent()` but was unable to access what I want. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to decode stringified object

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent());

$title       = $data->title;
$description = $data->description;
$hunter      = $data->hunter;
$encryption  = $data->encryption;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel request method "getContent" to get the data passed.

```
$content = json_decode($request->getContent());
```

If you like to send parsed JSON as object. Use,

```
data: JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify({
        title: stateCopy.title,
        description: stateCopy.value,
        hunter: stateCopy.selectedHunter.id,
        encryption: stateCopy.encryption
    })
)
```